# jquery count li elements inside ul -> length?

Tags: jquery

If a `ul` has more than one `li`-element inside of it, something should happen, otherwise not!

What am I doing wrong?

```
if ( $('#menu ul').length > 1 ) {
```

Answer (score 90):

You have to count the li elements not the ul elements:

```
if ( $('#menu ul li').length > 1 ) {
```

If you need every UL element containing at least two LI elements, use the filter function:

```
$('#menu ul').filter(function(){ return $(this).children("li").length > 1 })
```

You can also use that in your condition:

```
if ( $('#menu ul').filter(function(){ return $(this).children("li").length > 1 }).length) {
```

Answer (score 35):

The correct syntax is

```
$('ul#menu li').length
```

Answer (score 12):

```
alert( "Size: " + $( "li" ).size() );

alert( "Size: " + $( "li" ).length );
```

Both .size() and .length return number of item. but size() method is deprecated (JQ 1.8). .length property can use for instead of size().

also you can use

```
alert($("ul").children().length);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `$('ul#menu').children('li').length`

.size() instead of .length will also work

Answer (score 4):

Make the following change:

```
console.log($("#menu li").length);
```

Comment: kindly explain your answer. Simply adding a line of code that prints something doesn't really help in answering a question.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
</ul>   you need to count a number of li inside the ul tag using this(  $("#menu li").length )

Comment: ($("#menu li").length)  specify the  parent element id after that specify which child element count you want

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to count number of list elements:

```js
var num = $("#menu").find("li").length;
if (num > 1) {
  console.log(num);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a dom object of the ul, use the following.

```
$('#my_ul_id').children().length;
```

A simple example

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
  let ul = $('#ul');                 // Get the ul
  let length = ul.children().length; // Count of the child nodes.      

  // Append li.
  ul.append(`<li>Item ${length + 1}</li>`);

  // Reset after having more than 4 children.
  if (4 < length) {
    ul.empty();
    length = -1;
  }

  // Show the count of the children.
  $('#ul_length').text(++length);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Count of the child nodes: <span id='ul_length'>0</span></h4>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**: Answers above only work most of the time!

In jQuery version 3.3.1 (haven't tested other versions)

```
$("#myList li").length;
```

works only if your list items don't wrap. If your items wrap in the list then this code counts the number of lines occupied not the number of <li> elements.

```
$("#myList").children().length;
```

gets the actual number of <li> elements in your list not the number of lines that are occupied.

Answer (score 1):

```
('#menu li').length;
```

No need to mention `ul` because `id` is an unique element.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert( "Size: " + $("li").size() );
```

or

```
alert( "Size: " + $("li").length );
```

You can find some examples of the .size() method [here](http://api.jquery.com/size/).

Comment: **Just for further reference...** The `.size()` method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the `.length` property instead. [deprecated-1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/)