# How to count number of <li> from a specific <ul>?

Tags: jquery, sockets

I tried to count all append list `li` of the specific `ul` but it will count `0` when I console it.

I try to put this code:

```
count = $('#notif-list').children("li").length;
console.log(count);
```

and here is my full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

notif();

count = $('#notif-list').children("li").length;
console.log(count);
$('#countnotif').append('Notifications'+ '<span>'+ count     +'</span>');


var socket = io('http://www.iaccs-admin-console.test' + ':8080');
socket.on("message", function(message){

    notif()

});
```

The result should be like this.. if there are four `li` then `count = 4`.

This is the code where I append the list.

```
function notif(){

    $.ajax({
        url: `/iaccs-hook-notifications`,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data){

            console.log(data);          


            if (data.length > 0) {

                $('#btn-notif').addClass('js-has-new-notification'); 


                $('#notif-list').append(`

                    <li>

                        <div class="an-info-single unread">
                            <a href="{{url('iaccs-hook-list')}}">
                                <span class="icon-container important">
                                    <i class="icon-setting"></i>
                                </span>
                                <div class="info-content">
                                    <h5 class="user-name">Update Client</h5>
                                    <p class="content"><i class="icon-clock"></i> ${data[0].created_at}</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </li>
                `);

            }

        },
        error: function(err){
            swal('Error!','Please report this issue.', 'error');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please try `document.getElementById("notif-list").getElementsByTagName("li").length`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158649/jquery-count-li-elements-inside-ul-length

Comment: Can you please show us an example of your ul? It looks like children should work.

Comment: I edited my question @Rup.. I included the function where the li is appended.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```js
console.log($('.spacial-list-item').children('li').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="spacial-list-item">
<li class="linked">
    <span class="spacial-list-desc">App Testing Project</span>
</li>
<li class="">
    <span class="spacial-list-desc">Latest Test Project</span>
</li>
<li class="">
    <span class="spacial-list-desc">Latest Test Project</span>
</li>
<li class="">
    <span class="spacial-list-desc">New Test Project</span>
</li>    <li class="">
    <span class="spacial-list-desc">QA - Test project</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you change find to children in your example then it works fine, so OP must have some other problem. find will also count the number of items in nested lists too, so is different behaviour.

Comment: @Ghanshym the problen is I just append the list in AJAX please see the update question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

sir @Rup here is the append list function..

```
function notif(){

    $.ajax({
        url: `/iaccs-hook-notifications`,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data){

            console.log(data);


            if (data.length > 0) {

                $('#btn-notif').addClass('js-has-new-notification'); 

                $('#notif-list').append(`

                    <li>

                        <div class="an-info-single unread">
                            <a href="{{url('iaccs-hook-list')}}">
                                <span class="icon-container important">
                                    <i class="icon-setting"></i>
                                </span>
                                <div class="info-content">
                                    <h5 class="user-name">Update Client</h5>
                                    <p class="content"><i class="icon-clock"></i> ${data[0].created_at}</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </li>
                `);
            }



        },
        error: function(err){
            swal('Error!','Please report this issue.', 'error');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this. This is in Java, try to use this concept.

//Get elements in a List

```
    List<WebElement> l=driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

"l" is the list of all elements with tag name as "li".

//print count of a

```
    System.out.println(a.size());
```