# I need to check if an unordered list contains more than 3 list items using JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
    if ( $(".facet ul li").length > 3 ) {
        console.log("test");
   }
```

I'm trying to use this simple line of code, but it doesn't seem to look for the amount of children, but instead checks if the length is greather than 3.

I am using multiple unordered lists with the same class. The goal is to append an expand button to the ones who contain more than 3 list-items

Comment: And what the problem is? Do you have more than one unordered lists with same class `facet`? And what the goal is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery count li elements inside ul -> length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158649/jquery-count-li-elements-inside-ul-length)

Comment: Correct. I am using multiple unordered lists with the same class. The goal is to append an expand button to the ones who contain more than 3 list-items.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple lists then you need check the number of child `li` in each one individually before appending the button. The straightforward way to do that is with `each()` and `find()`:

```js
$(".facet ul").each(function() {
  var $ul = $(this);
  if ($ul.find('li').length > 3) {
    $ul.append('<li><button>Expand</button></li>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="facet">
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However this can be simplified to use `:has()` and the `:gt()` selector to avoid the explicit loop:

```js
$(".facet ul:has(li:gt(2))").append('<li><button>Expand</button></li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="facet">
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. For future reference, it helps a *lot* if you include your HTML in questions where you're trying to use JS to amend the DOM - that's most likely the reason for the downvotes

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is like,

```
<ul class="facet">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul class="facet">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
<ul class="facet">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

You can use following,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".facet").each(function (index) {
            if($(this).children([0]).length > 3){
                console.log("more than three");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if this works for you.