# miscalculated .length on click

Tags: html, jquery

I was wondering if anyone could provide me with any pointers or advice. I have a list structure, similar to this on my website:

```js
var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
 
 if ($k(".selected").length){
    
 $k(".token").click(function(e) {
    var n = $k( ".selected" ).length;
    $k( "#showcount" ).text( "There are " + n +
      "Tokens");
 
  });    
    
} else {
     
     $(this).n(".selected").remove()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="token">one</li>
   <li class="token">two</li>
   <li class="token selected">three</li>
   <li class="token">four</li>
   <li class="token selected">five</li>
</ul>

<div id="showcount"></div>
```

The problem I have is that, when I click on any number within the li, (The value is displayed as 1 within the "showcount" div - which is correct e.g. One `<li>` is selected.

However, when I deselect the `<li>`, rather than the counter going back down to 0, the count increases to 2 rather than going to zero.

Ideally, I want to count the number of `<li>` items which are selected. (I do have another plugin working in the background which is making the `<li>` already clickable. I'm just trying to incorporate a counter to display a value of how many `<li>` items are selected.

Comment: The if-statement is outside of the `.click()` event listener, so naturally, it is not taken into consideration when a click event is fired.

Comment: Hey @Ivar, ah thank you for your comment. I'm pretty much new to JS, so I'm just getting to know my way around it all at the moment! :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158649/jquery-count-li-elements-inside-ul-length

Comment: Why would it go back down? You are not removing any clasees.

Answer (score 0):

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Call after page is ready
selectTokens();

// Bind "click" event to all .token
$(".token").on("click", selectTokens);

/**
 * Toggle the .selected class on the .token clicked
 * Assign the count of .selected to div.count
 */
function selectTokens(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $(".count").text(`There are ${$(".selected").length} selected items.`);
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="token">one</li>
   <li class="token">two</li>
   <li class="token selected">three</li>
   <li class="token">four</li>
   <li class="token selected">five</li>
</ul>
<div class="count"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```